# How to save multiple plot in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I tried to save multiple plot in a loop, but It draw them over each other. what should I do?

sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'b':[0,1,1,0,1,1],'c':[0,0,0,1,1,1]})
for i in ['b','c']:
    img=sns.boxplot(data.a, groupby=data[i])
    fig = img.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(i)
```

Comment: Where is the code that position those images?

Comment: @przemo_li, I did't get your mention! Images will be save in your work place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to clear the data from the previous figure which is rolling over in the loop. This should work, noting `fig.clf()` as the end of each loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'b':[0,1,1,0,1,1],'c':[0,0,0,1,1,1]})
for i in ['b','c']:
    img=sns.boxplot(data.a, groupby=data[i])
    fig = img.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(i)
    fig.clf()
```